# Is there a way to wait for a Jframe to close before executing the rest of the code in a method?

Tags: java, wait

I created a method that creates an object, and also I've made a JFrame to capture the data. The problem is that when I run the method it creates the JFrame but it ends the execution while the JFrame is still running, so I have no chance to get the info that I need to create the object successfully.

This is the part of the code of interest.
The JFrame ventanaHora updates its static attribute cal, which is nothing but a Calendar variable.
the problem is that the variable cal doesnt get the value of the static variable cal after being updated.
So the rest of the code from ventana.setVisible(true) is executed without waiting for the jFrame to update the value of cal. I know I'm not being very clear but I hope I have explained myself

```
        VentanaHora ventanaHora = new VentanaHora();
        ventanaHora.setVisible(true);
        Calendar cal = VentanaHora.cal;
```

Comment: GUI code does not "wait".  You have to create a way for the user to tell you that the `Calendar` instance has been set, usually by left-clicking a `JButton`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: you can also add a listener to the JFrame to be activated when it is closing/closed || and by the little code posted in question, it looks like a modal dialog would be a good option (even JOptionPane) || the above mentioned *official*  tutorial [Creating a GUI with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) is a good start!